# How to loop characters in a string, printing words starting with certain character?

Tags: python, python-3.5

This is a problem I have solved but need to understand why I failed in my first attempt.

The goal is to print words(capitalized), starting from "h" and higher and excluding non-alpha.

The string is: "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"

This is my first attempt:

```
quote = input("Enter a quote: ")
word=""
for x in quote:
if x.isalpha()==True and len(x)>0:
    word+=x.lower()
else:
    if word[0]>="h" and len(word)>0:
        print(word.upper())
        word=""
    else:
        word=""

if word[0]>="h" and len(word)>0:
print(word.upper())
```

Resulting in:

```
Enter a quote: Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart
WHERESOEVER
YOU
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dubirka/PycharmProjects/dasho-project/dasho-
beginner.py", line 7, in <module>
    if word[0]>="h" and len(word)>0:
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But when I added "if word.isalpha()==True and" it worked:

```
    else:
        if word.isalpha()==True and word[0]>="h" and len(word)>0:
            print(word.upper())
            word=""
    else:
        word=""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because `word` is empty at first.

So

```
if word[0]>="h" and len(word)>0:
```

fails because the first condition triggers an exception (array out of bounds)

Now with:

```
if word.isalpha()==True and word[0]>="h" and len(word)>0:
```

`isalpha` returns `False` on empty string so no risk of accessing an out of bounds array (BTW no need to test against `True`, `word.isalpha()` alone is enough)

Note that the proper fix is to test "truth" of `word` first (i.e. test if not empty):

```
if word and word[0]>="h":
```

Comment: I see. I thought that 

    else:
        word=""

would take care of that.. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Your right and based on what you said I realized that if I would have changed the order, starting with if len(word)>0, then I wouldn't have had that problem.

Comment: @Dasho exactly. But use `if word` it's more idiomatic.

Comment: Speaking of idiomatic: comparing with literal `True` and `False` values isn't idiomatic either.  So instead of `if word.isalpha() == True:` just `if word.isalpha():`.

Comment: That's `True` :) but in that case, I don't think the `isalpha` test is needed anymore. I was just quoting OP code.